# Font-Face not working in Firefox 18.0.1 (code and URL included)

Tags: firefox, plugins, browser, firefox-addon, font-face

Hello and thanks a ton for any help with my problem.  Here are the facts:

The URL is www.thecloudz.net, regarding the navigation links at the very top, the font is called brooklyn.  The font on the URL appears correctly in Safari and Chrome, but not in Firefox.  I was told I may have a plugin installed that's interfering with font-face.

The font-face settings for the URL are below, 'rock salt' is the default font showing up in FF, but according to the code below it should first show brooklyn.  Why is it working on every browser except Firefox?  Please help if you can, thank you!

```
`/* CHANGES FONT FOR NAVIGATION */
@font-face {
    font-family: brooklyn;
    src: url('http://thecloudz.net/files/BROOKLYN.eot');
    src: url('http://thecloudz.net/files/BROOKLYN.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-    opentype'),
         url('http://thecloudz.net/files/brooklyn.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://thecloudz.net/files/BROOKLYN.TTF') format('truetype');
}

#navigation ul li a {
    font-family: brooklyn, 'rock salt', serif;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    padding-top: 7px;
    height: 50px;
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

Firefox enforces a same origin policy.

`http://thecloudz.net/` and `http://www.thecloudz.net/` are not the same.